# Is the universal covering surface orientable?

Tags: differential-geometry, surfaces, covering-spaces

Let $M$ be a smooth, say also closed (compact and without boundary) surface. Is it true that its universal covering surface is orientable?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By definition, a universal covering surface is simply connected. Simply connected manifolds are always orientable (because a path that witnesses the non-orientabiliy can't possibly be be contractible).

Comment: My doubt was: what about the projective plane? It is simply connected and non-orientable...

Comment: @Second: The real projective plane is not simply connected. If you construct the projective plane by identifying antipodes on a sphere, then how would you contract the closed loop that is formed by half a great circle?

Comment: Ok, that was what I was missing. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

Also, from the perspective of obstructions, the obstruction to orientability (first Stiefel-Whitney class)lives in first homology, which is zero for simply-connected spaces (trivially, Abelianizing the 0 group).